# Can you induce motion by changing magnetic field on a body which isn't magnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

In this [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMfNuP1Wozw&feature=youtu.be) of Lenz's law, the narrator starts with a substance which doesn't respond to the magnetic field of a bar magnet yet when he moves the bar magnet in relative motion to the copper coil, the coil responds by producing an oscillatory motion.. so, this leads to my question: Why does the
non magnetic copper coil able to respond only to the change of magnetic field ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the motion of the magnet represents a change in the magnetic field across the coil. The changing magnetic field induces currents in the coil. The currents create a magnetic field of their own. Thus the coil becomes, briefly, magnetic and the magnet is able to move it.